# How do you read values from a text file and store them in 2 different arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, input

The text file contains 52 lines that are in the format:

```
A .013420
B .000191
C .011222
...
```

I want to ignore the letters and  I need to extract the values from the file and store the first 26 in one array which I named freqOne[] and store the last 26 values in another array named freqTwo[].  I will later use these values for calculations.
here is my attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (){

   FILE *input1;
   /*char freqOne[26]; i use these arrays for attempt 1 
     char freqTwo[26];*/
   double freqOne[26];
   double freqTwo[26];


   input1 = fopen("test8.txt", "r");
   if(input1 == NULL){
      perror("test8.txt");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   /* attempt one: all the values print out correctly but idk how to use them :(*/

   /*while(fgets(freqOne, sizeof(freqOne), input1)){
     printf("%s", freqOne);
     }
     while(fgets(freqTwo, sizeof(freqTwo), input1)){
     printf("%s", freqTwo);
     }
    */

   /*fclose(input1);    */

   int h;
   int i;
   /* another attempt i made, this one prints out the a large negative number for every element :(*/
   for(i=0; i<26; i++){
      fscanf(input1,"%lf", &freqOne[i]);
      printf("%lf\n", freqOne[i]);

   }
   for(h=0;h<26; h++){
      fscanf(input1,"%lf", &freqTwo[h]);
      printf("%lf\n", freqTwo[h]);

   }    
   fclose(input1);

   /*a = (freqOne[0]-freqTwo[0])*(freqOne[0]-freqTwo[0]);
     printf("%lf", a);*/
}
```

In my first attempt, i was able to print out all the values correctly, but I am not sure how to use them.  I printed them out as strings, but when I try to print them out as %lf, it gave me 0's for every value.
In my second attempt, I did some googling and found that I should try the fscanf function, but this did not work for either and a large negative number was printed out for every value.  I am pretty stuck right now and out of ideas.

Comment: You need to use `atof()` function in C. Have look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/)

Comment: 1) `fscanf(input1,"%lf", &freqOne[i]);` --> `fscanf(input1,"%*s %lf", &freqOne[i]);` to ignore the A, B, C, etc. 2) Check result of `fscanf()`

Comment: @hagubear rather `strtod()`.

Comment: hello everyone, thanks for the replies.  @chux, your suggestion worked perfectly.  I tested the values by printing them out and I did some calculations just to make sure everything works.  Thank you for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

So OP can close this post:

To ignore the A,B,C, etc., use assignment suppression `'*'`

```
// fscanf(input1,"%lf", &freqOne[i]);
fscanf(input1,"%*s %lf", &freqOne[i]);
```

Always a good idea to check I/O function results:

```
if (fscanf(input1,"%*s %lf", &freqOne[i]) != 1) Handle_Unexpected_Input();
```